# Loop a list and compare it's elements to a condition c#

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I need to loop through a list. Each element should be compared to 2 conditions.

The problem is that for one element result can be True, for another False. I have to keep all these results and make the operation OR, in order to get the final result.

```
foreach (var elem in mappingList)
{
   if (elem._mappingStatus == enum_MappingStatus.E_MAPPING_OK 
     || elem._mappingStatus == enum_MappingStatus.E_MAPPING_OK_END)
    {
        statusConfiguration = true;
    }
    else
    {
        statusConfiguration = false;
    }
}
```

The problem that I don't know how to keep statusConfiguration for all elements and then compare them. If at leat one of the results is false then the final result should be also false.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you put `break;` after `statusConfiguration = true;`?

Comment: 'If a == E_MAPPING_OK and a == E_MAPPING_OK_END' will never be true unless both those enums have an identical value. Do they?

Comment: My bad there should be OR operator. I'll change right now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Any()` to determine if **not** any item with these conditions exists

> If at leat one of the results is false then the final result should
>   be also false

```
statusConfiguration = mappingList.Any(x => 
                      x._mappingStatus != enum_MappingStatus.E_MAPPING_OK &&       
                      x._mappingStatus != enum_MappingStatus.E_MAPPING_OK_END);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should break off the foreach after statusConfiguration has been 'falsed'.

```
bool statusConfiguration = true;
foreach (var elem in mappingList)
{
    if (elem._mappingStatus == enum_MappingStatus.E_MAPPING_OK 
    & elem._mappingStatus == enum_MappingStatus.E_MAPPING_OK_END)
    {
         statusConfiguration = true;
    }
    else
    {
        statusConfiguration = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (!statusConfiguration) {finalResult = false;}
```

Comment: This may help those you don't want to use LINQ.

Comment: Given the accepted answer, the first line should be `false` and the `break` should be in the `if`.